# Convert Auth item to array before use it Laravel 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I've working on User custom permission in Laravel 4, After login permissions(json string) stored in **`Auth::user()->permissions.`** as following:

```
$permissions =array(101,102);
DB::table('user')->where('id', Auth::user()->id)->update(['permissions' => json_encode($permissions)]);
```

But while I've checking permissions every time need to decode it to array:

```
if(in_array(1000, json_decode(Auth::user()->permissions)){

}
```

but I want something that make it to work like following:

```
if(in_array(1000, Auth::user()->usr_rights){

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a Accessor to your model :

```
public function getPermissionsAttribute($value)
{
    return json_decode($value);
}
```

and all you have to do is this :

```
if(in_array(1000, Auth::user()->permissions){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

This isnt the nicest way of doing it but works.

Example:

`$array = array('lastname', 'email', 'phone');`

`comma_separated = implode(",", $array);`

`echo $comma_separated; // lastname,email,phone`

U could save this string in an additional row in user table.

and then convert it back with [Explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

`$pizza  = "piece1, piece2, piece3, piece4, piece5, piece6";`

`$pieces = explode(",", $pizza);`

`echo $pieces[0]; // piece1`

`echo $pieces[1]; // piece2`